# Club World - Golden Souls Meta Needed!

Tags: trove

I’m trying to make a club world and I have like 100,000 Flux & 13 GS. I really need GSs, anyone know how to get some fast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fast Golden Souls:

1. Buy them from marketplace
2. Patron
3. Ore bonus day
4. Lots of Lasermancy (or bombs)
5. Biomes with lots of ores
6. Keep Digging

You can fetch about 100 Golden Souls in an hour of just constant speed bombing DragonfirePeaks with the large cave systems.

Those are the only ways.

Comment: Thx did what you said and got club ;)

Comment: Glad to hear. If you found the answer useful, you can rate it and mark it as the correct answer for this question.